# Jquery changes on element which is added dynamically is not working

Tags: jquery, dom, show-hide, dynamically-generated

Adding HTML dynamically to a container element.
the dynamically added HTMl has a element which have an onclick attribuut.
the onclick function of this element will be used to show a div element which is also added dynamically.

the last point is not working if i click on the element the function will be call.
but the element isn't shown.
its looks like that the browser don't redraw the changes.

Do somebody know what i am doing wrong??

sorry for my bad english if something is not clear please ask me.

see the sample code here

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span onclick="showSubjectContentInContainer('subjectContent')">Subject description</span>

        <div id="subjectContent" style="display: none;">
                <div >
                    <div>
                        [CONTENT]
                    </div>
                    <div class="showSubContent" onclick="showSubContent('subContent')">Click here to show Sub Content</div>
                    <div id="subContent" style="display: none;">
                        [SUB-CONTENT]
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showSubjectContentInContainer(subjectContentId)
        {
            //get inner html of the subjectContent and place it in the Container div
            var htmlSubjectContent = $("#" + subjectContentId).html();
            $('#container').html(htmlSubjectContent); //THIS WORK FINE
        }

        function showSubContent(subContentId)
        {
            //show the subContent which is added dynamically
            $("#"+subContentId).show(); //THIS NOT WORKING...!!
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I think I found the problem. `$("#subContentC").show();` points to the first `<div id="subContent"..` element and does .show() to that element instead of the dynamically created one.

Possible fixes.

1) [**working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vH4R2/34/) Basically instead of selecting the element with id (which will only select one) select it with class (so it runs .show() on all elements with the specific class)

`$("."+subContentId).show();`

---

2) [**working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vH4R2/36/) After creating the container (content and subcontent) delete the `subjectContent` div so id-naming wont clash any more

`$( "#subjectContent" ).remove();`

Comment: hi thanx for Reply, but this is not the solution because function what i have declared is been calling (showSubContent) so the event is working. only thing is if i change attribute by calling .show() the element is changing but i don't see it on the screen.

Comment: could you make a fiddle so I can play with your code?

Comment: glad I was able to help :D